# Apostrophecms: Allow to upload PDF file only

Tags: node.js, apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

I am having one field with relation. I want to upload only PDF files. Whereas I don't want to change the default setting for the `dgad-attachments` from app.js/default.js that allows all `office` type of files as those are needed in other places in project.

```
{
  name: '_file',
  type: 'joinByOne',
  withType: 'apostrophe-file',
  label: 'File',
  required: true,
  idField: 'fileId',
  filters: {
    projection: {
      slug: 1,
      title: 1,
      attachment: 1
    }
  },
  extensions: ['pdf'],
  extensionMaps: {},
  image: false
}
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll want to create a new file group in Apostrophe-attachments. You can use a file group to specify what types of files and/or extensions should be available when you add an apostrophe-attachments field to an object's schema. In order to add a file group that only contains PDFs, you will want to add this to the modules object in your app.js file:

```
'apostrophe-attachments': {
    fileGroups: [
        {
            name: 'pdf',
            label: 'Pdf',
            extensions: ['pdf'],
            image: false
        }
    ]
}
```

This will create a new file group that will only allow files with the extension 'pdf'. Apostrophe-files isn't a regular schema type (it can't be added to an object's schema like other objects can). Instead of using apostrophe-files, it would be better to use apostrophe-attachments, which can be given a file group to restrict what types of files are allowed. In order to specify that group in your attachment, your new field will end up looking like this:

```
{
  name: 'file',
  type: 'attachment',
  label: 'File',
  group: 'pdf',
  required: true
}
```

If you do decide you need to use a join directly to apostrophe-files, you will probably need to add some custom code in order to restrict the file type. If that is the case, you can find more information about apostrophe-files here:

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-files/

You will probably be able to look at the way apostrophe-attachments handles file groups and replicate the behavior if necessary:

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-attachments/

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I am really appreciate your efforts and time given to this issue. More I am looking for the specific piece change and not the global as app.js changes will not allow us to upload other files rather than PDF in other modules/pieces too.

Comment: This won't actually stop you from uploading other file types - all it will do is create a new file group that is just for PDFs. Anywhere you use apostrophe-attachments, you will have the choice to specify whichever file group you wish - in this case, it will only limit the file types you can use when you specify the file group 'pdf' in the schema of whichever object you're trying to add the attachment to. It won't effect the entire application unless you manually specify that file group on all apostrophe-attachment fields.

Comment: But I need type as `joinByOne` for making separate entry of the uploaded file as shown in above example.
I tied with your example where Download button is showing me `NaN` that is size of the file.

Comment: using joinByOne won't fix that. Using apostrophe-attachments is doing the same thing that joinByOne is doing, except its using the attachment type which adds extra tools. How are you trying to get the size of the file?

Comment: I am getting the file size by `{{ w._file.attachment.length | fileSize }}`. I tried to implement the code given by you. It's allowing to upload images too :) .